# Get epoch inside keras optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am writing a custom optimizer for keras and I need to update a variable after each epoch, however keras only appears to allow me to update it after each training iteration (basically after each batch). Is there any default way to do this so I do not have to specify the batch size to the optimizer manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Keras the epochs are stored and iterated within `Model.fit()` so you would need to write a custom training loop and write your logic at the end of the outer loop.

Code from: https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

```py
# Given a callable model, inputs, outputs, and a learning rate...
epochs = 2
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
  
        #Update your variable
```